# Hook KeyPress Event in C#

Tags: c#, windows, hook

I am reading few articles that explains hooking a key pressed by using globalKeyBoardHook() but didn't told where this dll is. How to get this class available. 
Please help how to get this dll. Is it a windows dll api or an external dll. ?

Currently I am reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540572/global-hook-keylogger-problem), [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx) article and not getting anything.

Can anyone explain all the terms used in the line below. It seems that we are importing a dll. But why like this since we can add dll by right clicking on refrences folder. Any reason

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
```

Comment: post some code it makes it possible for us to help

Comment: @Woot: I have not written a single line of code yet. I just tried to create an object of this class but couldn't found. So my very first Q of the application arose before starting

Comment: Create an object of what class?

Comment: globalKeyBoardHook() as mentioned in the question above

Comment: globalKeyBoardHook is his class name, not from the dll

Comment: check out source code for baby smash, i know that it hooks the keyboard: http://babysmash.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/55373. Checkout app.xaml.cs and KeyboardHooks.cs

Answer (score 4):

The `globalKeyBoardHook` class is just a class created by the author of the code project article you read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSLLKeyboardHook.aspx). If you look at that link you'll see a link called something like *Download source - 29.62 KB*. Try clicking on that link, downloading the file and inside there there'll be a globalKeyboardHook.cs file that you should add to your project.

That code will then call `SetWindowsHookEx` from `user32.dll`, but you don't really need to worry about that.

All in all, read through that article carefully, I think you might have missed some steps in how to use his code.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the GAC for these dlls.  Visual Studio should automatically handle the references for you.

Comment: The names are kernel32.dll and user32.dll

Comment: Do i need to add there refrences as no class is being displayed by default.

Comment: you need to write the class yourself, its just what he named it

Answer (score 0):

[Related Q&A on Global Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540572/global-hook-keylogger-problem)